# Nested for loops with if/else in python

Tags: python

simple situation,

I have the following: When I just have an if statement, it works correctly.

```
products = [1,2,3,4,5]
orders = [1,2,3,4,5]

for product in products:
    for order in orders:
        if product == order:
            print("in list")
```

Results:

```
in list
in list
in list
in list
in list
```

However when adding an else it doesn't work correctly.

```
for product in products:
    for order in orders:
        if product == order:
            print("in list")
        else:
            print("not in")
```

Results:

```
in list
not in
not in
not in
not in
not in
```

How can I fix it?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to find out?  If you want to know whether an order is in your product list, then do that: `if product in orders:`.  What you have will run 25 loops,  5 of them will match, 20 will not.

Comment: Try printing `product` and `order` to debug what is happening.

Comment: I concur with Tim Roberts, we can’t help you until we know what you want the program to do.

Comment: Also this can’t be all your output unless you have a bug somewhere else. You should see 5 times as much output as this as Tim mentioned. Is this really all the output you’re seeing? If so do you have more code than you showed us? And of course first of all we need to know what the program should do.

Comment: I did not include the original code in the question since It was a bit complicated. However, the essence of what I would like to is is compare two lists, and create a new list with similar number of element as the outer-loop.  Example compare list 1 = [A,B,C] and  list 2=[A,C] if match /else if no match > generate a new list, list3 = ['MATCH FOR A' , NO BACH FOR B', 'MACH FOR C'].

Comment: also because the structure of my code I cannot use just the 'in' keyword with just one loop, I have to iterate through each item in both lists.

Comment: It works correctly with no else statement and incorrectly with an else statement. Why do you want to make it incorrect?

Comment: I used a list to make the example simpler but in my code I'm looping through a dictionary and comparing one key of this dictionary with the key of another dictionary. If the values match I want to append to a third dictionary with key { "product _id='15', order_id='15"} if the product is not ordered I want to have a null or none value for order id.  I need the final list to have the same number of elements as the first loop.

Answer (score 3):

The `set` type is a better choice when you want to check if item is in a unique "list of item", e.g.

Lets consider the case where orders are non-unique and products are unique,

```
products = [1,2,3,4,5]
orders = set([1,2,3,4,5])

for p in products:
    if p in orders:
        print(f'product {p} in orders set')
    else:
        print(f'product {p} not in orders set')
```

Note: Here we use the f-string where you can print to see which `p` is in the order set.

---

Lets go back to the code in the original question, you have 2 lists and you want to iterate through the inner list for every outer list. Instead of calling it products/orders, lets call it outer/inner:

```
outer = [1,2,3,4,5]
inner = [6,7,8,9,0]

for o in outer:
    for i in inner:
        print(o, i)
```

[output]:

```
1 6
1 7
1 8
1 9
1 0
2 6
2 7
2 8
2 9
2 0
3 6
3 7
3 8
3 9
3 0
4 6
4 7
4 8
4 9
4 0
5 6
5 7
5 8
5 9
5 0
```

If you have a nested loop, `for o in outer for i in inner`, you will be iterating through all pairs of items in the outer list then the inner list.

---

Now lets go back to the if else part, if we are looping through the outer list then the inner list and if you only check on the outer list, with an `if` but not catching the else, you will not be seeing the results when it doesn't fall into the condition.

You can see this effect by adding the if-else after a print statement on every iteration, e.g.

```
outer = [1,2,3,4,5]
inner = [6,7,8,9,0]

for o in outer:
    for i in inner:
        print('printing always', o, i)
        if o + 5 == i: # We are checking if outer+5=inner, i.e. 1+5= 6, 2+5=7, etc. 
            print('printing only when outer+5=inner', o, i)
```

[out]:

```
printing always 1 6
printing only when outer+5=inner 1 6
printing always 1 7
printing always 1 8
printing always 1 9
printing always 1 0
printing always 2 6
printing always 2 7
printing only when outer+5=inner 2 7
printing always 2 8
printing always 2 9
printing always 2 0
printing always 3 6
printing always 3 7
printing always 3 8
printing only when outer+5=inner 3 8
printing always 3 9
printing always 3 0
printing always 4 6
printing always 4 7
printing always 4 8
printing always 4 9
printing only when outer+5=inner 4 9
printing always 4 0
printing always 5 6
printing always 5 7
printing always 5 8
printing always 5 9
printing always 5 0
```

Now, we see that the normal loop print always prints, and if condition prints only when the condition is met.

To check when what is printed with an if and else, you can do something like:

```
outer = [1,2,3,4,5]
inner = [6,7,8,9,0]

for o in outer:
    for i in inner:
        print('printing always', o, i)
        if o + 5 == i: # We are checking if outer+5=inner, i.e. 1+5= 6, 2+5=7, etc. 
            print('printing only when outer+5=inner', o, i)
        else:
            print('printing otherwise', o, i)
        print('------------')
```

[output]:

```
printing always 1 6
printing only when outer+5=inner 1 6
------------
printing always 1 7
printing otherwise 1 7
------------
printing always 1 8
printing otherwise 1 8
------------
printing always 1 9
printing otherwise 1 9
------------
printing always 1 0
printing otherwise 1 0
------------
printing always 2 6
printing otherwise 2 6
------------
printing always 2 7
printing only when outer+5=inner 2 7
------------
printing always 2 8
printing otherwise 2 8
------------
printing always 2 9
printing otherwise 2 9
------------
printing always 2 0
printing otherwise 2 0
------------
printing always 3 6
printing otherwise 3 6
------------
printing always 3 7
printing otherwise 3 7
------------
printing always 3 8
printing only when outer+5=inner 3 8
------------
printing always 3 9
printing otherwise 3 9
------------
printing always 3 0
printing otherwise 3 0
------------
printing always 4 6
printing otherwise 4 6
------------
printing always 4 7
printing otherwise 4 7
------------
printing always 4 8
printing otherwise 4 8
------------
printing always 4 9
printing only when outer+5=inner 4 9
------------
printing always 4 0
printing otherwise 4 0
------------
printing always 5 6
printing otherwise 5 6
------------
printing always 5 7
printing otherwise 5 7
------------
printing always 5 8
printing otherwise 5 8
------------
printing always 5 9
printing otherwise 5 9
------------
printing always 5 0
printing otherwise 5 0
------------
```

Answer (score 2):

This is working correctly.
One the first loop its comparing 1 to 1,2,3,4,5 then 2 to 1,2,3,4,5.
So because the if statement is true for at least one item in the loop, it will print every time its true. You don't have an else condition so every time it is not true, it doesn't do anything. The full output would be:

```
in list
not in
not in
not in
not in
not in
in list
not in
not in
not in
not in
not in
in list
not in
not in
not in
not in
not in
in list
not in
not in
not in
not in
not in
in list
```

Answer (score 1):

In the second code, the total print statement executed will be 25 ( len(products) * len(orders) ).

You'll still get 5 "in list" in output, because when if statement result false, it'll go to else statement and print "not in".